# css display behave differently on some iphone models

Tags: css, ios

I have a very odd occasion on my website css. I am using bootstrap columns to align my modules in the rows but in some iphone modules (iphone 6-7-11), the display property behaves differently than other iphone models. My website is [https://mgcosmetics.gr/el/](http://mgcosmetics). My problem is with the cart button at the main menu on the mobile version. I want it to be as the first image. Tell me if you need whole css files because they are big! Thank you in advance for your time!

**Correct way of presenting (chrome dev tools desktop, mobile view) :**
[image: chrome dev tools desktop, mobile view]

**Iphone 6 browserstack simulator dev tools:**
[image: browserstack simulator dev tools]

Comment: _“Tell me if you need whole css files because they are big!”_ - no, what we would need from you, is a [mre].

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878) +++ [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

After hours on that problem i found the solution. I'll post it here in case someone face the same occurrence. Also I haven't found a solution to this anywhere else. The problem was in css

```
display: table;
```

which for some very strange reason behaves differently in some iphone devices regardless of the ios version! I changed
`display: table;` to `display: block;` and now all the devices show the same thing.